# Which firebase database faster for mobile application?

Tags: database, firebase, react-native

I am new to mobile application development. I am preparing an application in React Native. In my application, 1000 words and 1000 sentences about these words will be in 2 languages. There will also be a picture for each word. By pressing the button in the application, the user will see the words, sentences in both languages and the picture of the word. Which database in firebase makes the application run faster? Firestore Database or Realtime Database?

Comment: Recommending a technology is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but consider the Firebase database recommender is a tool to help you make this choice yourself: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: I can't make my choice. I need someone to say me which one is good for this project and why? I need someone help as i am very new to mobile app development.

Comment: Both are really fast. You have read the article indicated by Frank van Puffelen? Do you have any questions?